# SSL on Android (via BouncyCastle)

Tags: android, ssl, bouncycastle

http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

I followed this tutorial and everything seemed to be fine (I didn't get any error(s) on the road) but again I get

```
06-24 18:42:31.746: WARN/System.err(14807): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
06-24 18:42:31.756: WARN/System.err(14807): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
06-24 18:42:31.766: WARN/System.err(14807): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
```

I have SSL on http://subdomain.domain.com - **RapidSSL**. I downloaded the (single) certificate and inserted it into **keystore**. Added **myHttpClient** but again, I can't get **https** to work.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** On desktop everything is just fine - I don't get any errors/warnings at all.

Comment: If you visit the same address on desktop, do you get successful connection or you some warning about server's certificate?

Comment: On desktop everything works as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try http://www.digicert.com/help/ for example - paste in the URL of your site and you will see if the certificate is correctly installed. Usually to get the certificate correctly installed you do not only have to install the certificate but also an intermediate certficate from your certificate authority. They usually sign your certs not with their main certificate but using some intermediate ones that they can invalidate in case of any problems and which is not as "precious" as the main one - which means that your certificate is third in the chain:

main authority certificate -> intermediate authority certificate -> your own certificate

So you have to tell your client not only your certificate, but also the intermediate one. 
Installation instructions are usually available at your certifcation authority account.

Comment: I checked and everything is fine and yes - I have two certificates listed - server certificate + intermediate certificate. I'll install both and see if it works.

Comment: You can also take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1946  which I think describes other's struggle with the same problem.

Comment: It works flawlessly :) I need to add as you said - 3 certificates from mine to the main, so my own -> intermediate -> main. After they are all inserted into keystore everything is working.

Answer (score 5):

**Detailed Step by Step instructions I followed to achieve this**

- Download bouncycastle JAR from 
          http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on/1.46/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar
  or take it from the "doc" folder.
- Configure BouncyCastle for PC using one of the below methods.

  - Adding the BC Provider Statically (Recommended)

    - Copy the bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar to each

      - D:\tools\jdk1.5.0_09\jre\lib\ext   (JDK (bundled JRE)
      - D:\tools\jre1.5.0_09\lib\ext       (JRE)
      - C:\                                (location to be used in env variable)
    - Modify the java.security file under

      - D:\tools\jdk1.5.0_09\jre\lib\security
      - D:\tools\jre1.5.0_09\lib\security
      - and add the following entry

        - security.provider.7=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
    - Add the following environment variable in "User Variables" section

      - CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;c:\bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar
  - Add bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar to CLASSPATH of your project and Add the following line in your code

    - Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
- Generate the Keystore using Bouncy Castle

  - Run the following command

    - keytool -genkey -alias myproject -keystore C:/myproject.keystore -storepass myproject -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
  - This generates the file C:\myproject.keystore
  - Run the following command to check if it is properly generated or not

    - keytool -list -keystore C:\myproject.keystore -storetype BKS
- Configure BouncyCastle for TOMCAT

  - Open D:\tools\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\conf\server.xml and add the following entry

    - <Connector
      port="8443"
      keystorePass="myproject"
      alias="myproject"
      keystore="c:/myproject.keystore"
      keystoreType="BKS"
      SSLEnabled="true"
      clientAuth="false"
      protocol="HTTP/1.1"
      scheme="https"
      secure="true"
      sslProtocol="TLS"
      sslImplementationName="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"/>
  - Restart the server after these changes.
- Configure BouncyCastle for Android Client

  - No need to configure since Android supports Bouncy Castle Version 1.46 internally in the provided "android.jar".
  - Just implement your version of HTTP Client (MyHttpClient.java can be found below) and set the following in code

    - SSLSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
  - If you don't do this, it gives an exception as below

    - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <192.168.104.66> !=
  - In production mode, change the above code to

    - SSLSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

**MyHttpClient.java**

```
package com.arisglobal.aglite.network;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;

import com.arisglobal.aglite.activity.R;

import android.content.Context;

public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    final Context context;

    public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();

        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

        // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore to the ConnectionManager
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

            // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.aglite);
            try {
                // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates.
                // Also provide the password of the keystore
                trusted.load(in, "aglite".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }

            // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible for the verification of the server certificate.
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);

            // Hostname verification from certificate
            // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            return sf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

How to invoke the above code in your Activity class:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(...);
```

Comment: When I try to create the keystore I get the error: erro de keytool: java.security.KeyStoreException: java.io.IOException: Error initialising store of key store: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size. Someone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Find and download **Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files** in
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Overwrite the **local_policy.jar** and **US_export_policy.jar** in both your JDK's

> jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security\

and in your JRE's

> jre7\lib\security\

folder.